# Reload APNs token every time my app is relaunched [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

today I’m having a doubt about `apnsToken` function from `Firebase's Messaging` object… I’m reading that apnsToken should be unique until the app has been reinstalled, but I want to know if it’s possible to **change this value per launch**, I mean, we’re having troubles in a solution because the apns is the same in a certain device, we are changing accounts but it’s possible to have THE SAME APNs token in multiple accounts and the problem is that notifications are getting received in the same device using different accounts and that’s not good because we are mixing push notifications in accounts, so **we need to have a unique apnsToken per launch** but I’m not sure if it’s possible or not… Hope you can help me to understand about it. Thank you so much.

Here’s a little documentation I have read

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: The apns token can change but this is not under your control. You need to implement code in your server to ensure that a given token is only registered against the most recent user that has reported it; ie if user A has the token registered and then user B reports the same token, you must remove the association with user a and establish an association with user b